I need upload verification file without re-build nuxt app
I want to upload a temporary file for site verification in the root directory of the site.
This file should be under the public directory, but I don't want to put it in the source code and code repository because it needs to be repackaged.
I would like to add it to the already generated .output/public folder of the site and delete it after verification.
I have found that after packaging, a mapping is created for the public folder in the file .output/server/chunks/runtime.mjs where the variable assets is defined.
How can I solve this problem?

try re-build app
i neeed upload verification file without re-build nuxt app
